# \frac not putting first input over the numerator under very weird conditions

Tags: overleaf, fractions

I'm basically brand new to Latex, so maybe this has a really simple answer I'm not seeing, but I'm having a problem where \frac isn't putting my first input over the numerator but instead to the side of the fraction.

the code looks like this

```
$\limi a_n=\limi \frac{1}{2} $
```

but it ends up looking like this

[image]

---

It's worth noting that `\limi` is a custom command I made with code

```
\newcommand{\limi}{$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$}
```

---

In addition, If I change `\frac` to be `\tfrac` or `\dfrac` it works just fine

Ex.

```
$\limi a_n=\limi \dfrac{1}{2} $
```

[image]

---

And last thing I've noticed is that if I delete my `\limi` command it fixes the problem, and `\frac` works like normal. So I'm guessing that it has something to do with my command code, but I can't figure out what's causing it. Help would be very much appreciated.

P.S.(I know that this equation doesn't make any sense, I changed the fraction to test the code, and so it would be easier to see)

Comment: never ignore error messages, remove the `$`  from your definition, you are already in math mode so `\limi` does not need to start math mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the simple example

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\limi}{$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$}

\begin{document}

$\limi a_n=\limi \frac{1}{2} $

\end{document}
```

and hit return when errors are raised, I get the following on the console

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2022/dev) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./limi.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-08-27>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file limi.aux.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.7 $\limi
           a_n=\limi \frac{1}{2} $
?
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.7 $\limi a_
             n=\limi \frac{1}{2} $
?
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.7 $\limi a_n=\limi
                     \frac{1}{2} $
?
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.7 $\limi a_n=\limi \frac{1}{2}
                                 $
?
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\frac  #1#2->{\begingroup #1\endgroup \over #2}

l.7 $\limi a_n=\limi \frac{1}{2}
                                 $
?
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./limi.aux) )
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### simple group (level 1) entered at line 7 ({)
### bottom level</usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts
/cm/cmmi7.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmr7.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cms
y7.pfb>
Output written on limi.pdf (1 page, 36624 bytes).
Transcript written on limi.log.
```

When TeX issues an error message, it's essentially impossible to obtain correct output if one simply scrolls past errors.

Modify your code into

```
\newcommand{\limi}{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}}
```

and you'll get no error, but dubiously useful output, because `\limits` will make the formula too big vertically to fit in a line. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\limi}{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}}

\begin{document}

some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
$\limi a_n=\limi \frac{1}{2} $
some text some text some text some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some text some text some text 

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Remove also `\limits`.